# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given in

Tags: php, mysql

the warning message above is shown when the site is searched. It is a simple search feature which displays all the records, matching the search word with a field in the table. The code is as below.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

$clean_search_word = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['search_word']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM webdir_user where user_category like '%$clean_search_word%'"; 

        $record = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if(!$record){
        die('Error in SQL:'.mysql_error());
          }
        else{
        while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($record,$con)){
        }   
    }

}
```

I have found answers to kind of same issues as mine, but in most of the cases the warning message was caused by something else so I couldn't find any help with figuring out what caused the problem in my case. Any help or advise as to how to resolve. Thank you.

Comment: this question have been answered many times, please browse through SO, before asking any question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `$con` from your `mysqli_fetch_array` and it should work. There is only 1 string allowed in this 'function'. The other one ($con) is optional and has to be an integer. Like `MYSQLI_ASSOC`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

$clean_search_word = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['search_word']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM webdir_user where user_category like '%$clean_search_word%'"; 

    $record = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(!$record){
    die('Error in SQL:'.mysql_error());
      }
    else{
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($record)){
    }   
}

}
```

Comment: @Gobbin..Thanks a lot. I just realized the mistake before I looked at your answer. I shall accept your answer in a few minutes. Thanks for your time

Comment: Also, you are using mysqli but in the if statement - if you cant execute the query - you are giving a mysql_error. That should be a mysqli_error(); :)

Comment: Answer accepted as it is the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

[mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)
takes one parameter (the $result)
another optional one which is INTEGER (int $resulttype = MYSQLI_BOTH )